# Docker apache guacamole - GUACAMOLE_HOME wont change

Tags: docker, tomcat, docker-compose, guacamole

I use apache guacamole on docker-compose, and it seems that it is impossible to edit tomcat HTML files.
I really need to delete the user "home" button from control panel (ctrl + alt+ shift)

I have tried adding new extension but i cant because when i set
`GUACAMOLE_HOME` to "/guacamole-home" where i created a .jar of new extension its always setting it to the default "/root/.guacamole".

How can I make this work? even if there's another way to edit the client.html in guacamole on another way

```
guacamole:
                image: guacamole/guacamole:latest
                depends_on:
                      - guacd
                      - postgres_gqm
                volumes:
                        - /root/api/program.jar:/opt/guacamole/program.jar
                        - /root/api/guacamole-home:/guacamole-home
                environment:
                        - "enable-environment-properties=true"
                        - "GUACD_HOSTNAME=guacd"
                        - "POSTGRES_DATABASE=guacamole_db"
                        - "POSTGRES_HOSTNAME=postgres_gqm"
                        - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass"
                        - "POSTGRES_USER=guacamole_user"
                        - "GUACD_LOG_LEVEL=debug"
                        - "GUACAMOLE_HOME=/guacamole-home"
                links:
                     - guacd
                ports:
                     - 8080/tcp
                restart: always
```

Comment: Can you verify from the tomcat logs if the extension is loaded? There should be a line for each loaded extension, something like 'INFO  o.a.g.extension.ExtensionModule - Extension "blah blah" loaded'.

Comment: @mnikolic I cannot load an extension if i cant put it under  GUACAMOLE_HOME/extensions, and as i cannot mount GUACAMOLE_HOME i cannot add the new extension..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to change tomcat HTML files on guacamole using an extension but not in the way docs suggested.

First, I copied this files from container guacamole to host :

```
docker cp <containerid>:/usr/local/tomcat /root/myhome
docker cp <containerid>:/opt/guacamole/bin/start.sh /root/myhome
```

Then When i Have the files I can edit the `client.html` that is under
`tomcat/webapps/guacamole/app/client/templates/client.html` on my local host.

So the way I made the extension is first you go to the start.sh script that
I copied on localhost and add this row to this lines number:

```
238:    ln -s /opt/guacamole/program.jar "$GUACAMOLE_EXT"
389:    ln -s /opt/guacamole/program.jar "$GUACAMOLE_EXT"
```

should be here on the start.sh:

```
# Add required .jar files to GUACAMOLE_LIB and GUACAMOLE_EXT
ln -s /opt/guacamole/postgresql/postgresql-*.jar "$GUACAMOLE_LIB"
ln -s /opt/guacamole/postgresql/guacamole-auth-*.jar "$GUACAMOLE_EXT"
ln -s /opt/guacamole/program.jar "$GUACAMOLE_EXT" #ADDED
```

and here:

```
# Add required .jar files to GUACAMOLE_LIB and GUACAMOLE_EXT
ln -s /opt/guacamole/mysql/mysql-connector-*.jar "$GUACAMOLE_LIB"
ln -s /opt/guacamole/mysql/guacamole-auth-*.jar "$GUACAMOLE_EXT"
ln -s /opt/guacamole/program.jar "$GUACAMOLE_EXT" #ADDED
```

Now, we need to make the extention and the changes we want to the HTML and JS:
in localhost:

```
mkdir myExt
cd myExt
```

`vi guac-manifest.json` #creating the guac-manifest.json

```
{   "guacamoleVersion" : "*",

    "name"      : "B-Override",
    "namespace" : "b-override",

    "html" : [ "client.html" ],
    "js": ["clientController.js"]
}
```

I wanted to change client.html and clientController.js (it doesn't matter if you replace the names of the original files, i choose not to replace the original names in the `guac-manifest.json`.

I wanted to remove from user panel menu `(ctrl+alt+shift)` the connection dropdown + the options to logout or go to home so i copied the original client.html from the tomcat file we copied to localhost:

```
cp ../tomcat/webapps/guacamole/app/client/templates/client.html .
```

and also:

```
cp ../tomcat//webapps/guacamole/app/client/controllers/clientController.js .
```

Because i wanted to remove the home and logout button also from the popup that guacamole gives when the vm is off.(reconnect - home - logout)

Now,

I edited the files i just copied to myExt:

```
vi client.html
```

I add to the top of the file this :

```
<meta name="replace-children" content=".menu .menu-content .header">
```

And it replace the parts in the HTML that i want , i can remove from the file the parts that i don't edit and it will only replace in the original file the class i add in the content

little example:

```
<meta name="replace-children" content=".menu .menu-content .header">
    <div class="menu" ng-class="{open: menu.shown}" id="guac-menu">
        <div class="menu-content" ng-if="menu.shown">

            <!-- Stationary header -->
            <div class="header">
                <h2 class="connection-select-menu" ng-show="rootConnectionGroups">
                    <guac-menu menu-title="client.name" interactive="true">
```

You can that the classes on the code that i wanted to replace i added to content with a "." in front of it (that is how i understand on how to replace the parts, i know it is related to css files but that way made it easier for me to understand)

in the js that i wanted to modify i didn't deleted the parts that i don't need to change as it doesn't works the same, i went to "action = " and deleted the `HOME` and `LOGGOUT` option and saves it like that, no need anything on the file head like HTML.

now that the extension is ready we need to make it as a jar file + volume the start.sh to guacamole container:

first we need to install this to have the jar option: (ubuntu)

```
apt install default-jdk openjdk-11-jdk-headless fastjar openjdk-8-jdk-headless
```

then we go out of the myExt dir :

```
cd ..

jar cvf program.jar -C myExt .
```

now we go to `docker-compose.yml` and adding the volumes:

```
guacamole:
        image: guacamole/guacamole:latest
        depends_on:
              - guacd
              - postgres_gqm
        volumes:
                - /root/myhome/start.sh:/opt/guacamole/bin/start.sh #ADDED
                - /root/myhome/program.jar:/opt/guacamole/program.jar #ADDED
        environment:
                - "GUACD_HOSTNAME=guacd"
                - "POSTGRES_DATABASE=guacamole_db"
                - "POSTGRES_HOSTNAME=postgres_gqm"
                - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=PassWrdGQM"
                - "POSTGRES_USER=guacamole_user"
                - "GUACD_LOG_LEVEL=debug"
        links:
             - guacd
        ports:
             - 8080/tcp
        restart: always
```

now :

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d ; docker-compose logs -f --tail=10 guacamole
```

and look for the extension load :

```
guacamole_1       | 09:50:10.683 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.a.g.extension.ExtensionModule - Extension "B-Override" loaded.
```

If you see that you made a mistake you can always go back and try again by deleting the
`/root/myhome/program.jar` from localhost, go back to `myEXT` re-copy `client.html` file or edit it, closing it again as jar and `docker-compose down + up`.

Comment: Really good answer, although a little bit cryptic did the magic!!! Thanks!!!